Adapting prediction model
I try to predict values that basically follow a negative exponential / asymptotic density function. The prediction is not so bad, only that I want to correct it further so that decline is stronger so that the predicted value for 2023 should be 38,410. But then it should reach a symptotic area where it does not drop any further for a longer time period, not below 30,0000.
How can I do that without changing my actual data?
I have never done that before.
DF stores my actual data:
DF <- structure(list(YEAR = c(1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023
), N_1 = c(10495614, 9907864, 9352674, 9737358, 
10272632, 10594012, 10291692, 10057796, 10548570, 10619598, 10624400, 
10478856, 10564030, 11040320, 10983744, 11074778, 11155158, 11111134, 
10792690, 10792076, 10753846, 10763378, 10395126, 10248014, 10247884, 
10126604, 10113030, 9791064, 9290348), N_2 = c(818058, 
734480, 895984, NA, 444498, 358780, 314442, 269460, 253768, 225876, 
170940, 169512, 159390, 129192, 129272, 119996, 110128, 90870, 
73228, 71520, 65310, 65090, 60020, 57176, 54264, 45132, 42388, 
38410, 37552), company_N = c(237976, 224160, NA, NA, 190546, 172482, 
158040, 150694, 137588, 126716, 102530, 108712, 90072, 95080, 
79674, 76004, 61610, 61882, 57714, 53446, 51282, 52150, 48448, 
47604, 44368, 42184, 42080, 38402, 35512)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))

mod_1 <- nls(N_2 ~ SSasymp(YEAR, Asym, R0, lrc), data = DF)
predicted_2024 <- (predict(mod_1, newdata = data.frame(Jahr=2024)) %>% round)[1]

Can someone show me how to do that?
I tried different R functions. I do not know how to write a formula describing/aprroximating a negative asymptotic function that comes close to my empiric data.

Use the weights= argument to nls and specify a higher weight for the point of interest.
